# Unexpected end of file error with valid code

Tags: php

```
<?php if (arg(1) == 40): ?>
    <?php
        $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'home_rotator-block');
        print render($block['content']);
    ?>            
<? endif; ?>
```

For some reason this code is causing causing an  unexpected end of file error pointing to the end of the file. I know that this code is valid because it works on my other server. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be throwing the error?

Note: I know it can be formatted differently(without the  inside the if statement.

I get the same error when I comment out the $block line and the print line.

Comment: what happens if you change <? endif; ?> to <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Short PHP tags may not be supported on the new server. Instead of using the short tags `<?` and `?>`, use the full ones: `<?php` and `?>`

Or, if you want to enable that on your new server, just change the directive in your `php.ini` file:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

But however, `<?php` is the official standard and I recommend you use it everywhere so you won't have to change it every time you switch between servers.

Answer (score 0):

You're using short tags for the last line. This could very well not be enabled on your server. Check php.ini to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maximus2012 was able to answer the question. I had to to change `<?` to `<?php`.

Thanks Maximus2012